# Multiple data-based transitions in D3.js

Tags: csv, d3.js, transition

Let's say I have this data in age.csv. The six columns contain the name and age of three people at different years.

```
"name","1990","1992","1993","1994","1995"
"Rob",0,1,2,3,4,5
"Angie",15,16,17,18,19
"Chris",41,42,43,44,45
```

Say I want to represent each person with a circle.

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", 1000)
            .attr("height", 1000);

d3.csv("age.csv", function (data) {
       var people = svg.selectAll("circle")
                       .data(data)
                       .enter()
                       .append("circle")
                           .attr("cx", function(d) {return d[1990] * 10;})
                           .attr("cy", function(d, i) {return i*40; })
                           .attr("r", 20)
                           .attr("fill", "red");
});
```

Furthermore, I want the circles to move along the x-axis, starting from each persons age in the year 1990 to their age in 1995. To create an animation from one year to another, I simply use `transition().attr("x", function (d) {return d[1991] * 10;})`.

But what if I want to repeat this process to transition through every year in the data? I've tried different approaches using `.each("end", changeYear())` with `changeYear()` being a recursive function, but I only get to one or two transitions before the x-position of each element collapses and defaults to 0.

I'm utterly confused and could really use someone pointing me in the right direction.

**EDIT:**
Sorry for making this a really long post, but this is my faulty `changeYear()` recursive function. Using this, I also added `.each(changeYear());` as the last line of the `people` variable above.

```
var x = 0;
var years = [1990,1991,1992,1993,1994,1995);

function changeYear() { 
        return function() {
            x++;
            d3.select(this)
            .transition()
            .duration(1000)
            .attr("x", function (d) {return d[years[x]] * 10;})
            .each("end",change());
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's the definition of `changeYear()`? How does it know which year to transition to?

Comment: It's hard to explain since the code in my original post is just a simplified version of my original code. But, in short, I tried declaring a global variable `x` and a global array `years[]` and let x increase for every recursion, thereby changing the index of `years[]`. Formulating the recursive function is the core of my problem. I'm new to recursive functions.

Comment: Sounds like something is going wrong with your global variable. Try passing the value of `x` to the function and increase it when passing it on.

Comment: I tried that. I posted the function in my original post above. Can you see where the problem lies?

Comment: You shouldn't need the nested function. I assume that the `change()` at the end is supposed to be `changeYear()`? I think the issue is a race condition that occurs somewhere. I would change the code to pass in the entire set of data (i.e. all data for one year) after an interval and use a more d3-like pattern to update the positions.

Comment: I'm not sure how to translate your answer into code.

Comment: Have an update function that takes an array of data (all the data for a year) and then does a `.selectAll(...).data(...).transition(...)...`.